# ManyToOne from multiple entities into one

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have 3 entities:

- client
- company
- contact

`client` entity can have multiple `contact` entities, also `company` can have multiple `contact` entities.

`Contact` entity looks like this:

```
class ContactDetail
{
    use Timestampable;
    use Bleamable;

    CONST TYPE_EMAIL = 'EMAIL';
    CONST TYPE_PHONE = 'PHONE';
    CONST TYPE_FAX = 'FAX';
    CONST TYPE_MOBILE = 'MOBILE';

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Expose
     * @JMS\Groups({"ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", columnDefinition="ENUM('EMAIL', 'PHONE', 'FAX', 'MOBILE')", nullable=false)
     * @Expose
     * @JMS\Groups({"ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN"})
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter proper value")
     * @Expose
     * @JMS\Groups({"ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN"})
     */
    private $value;
   (...)
   }
```

The question is:

Should I do it in this way:

`client` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CoreBundle\Entity\ContactDetail", mappedBy="client")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contactDetail", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $contactDetails;
```

`company` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CoreBundle\Entity\ContactDetail", mappedBy="company")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contactDetail", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $contactDetails;
```

Which will creates two additional columns (company and client) in the contact entity or should I do it in some other way?

Ex.
Create two columns: `entityName` and `entityId` and bind it somehow to `client` and `company`? 
If second is proper way, please tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: Unless a contact can work for more than one client, or more than one company (depending on the profession, a contact frequently will work for more than one client), then the contact should reference the client and/or company they work for. If a client can work for multiples, then there should be an intermediate entity which ties each contact to their clients and companies. Note that companies, especially, often have more than one contact.  In general, unless you know relationships will always be 1 <-> 1, use an intermediate connection to hold the relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to solve this using a unidirectional map from Client and Company to Contact. In this case is a little trick because there is no way to create a `OneToMany` relationship without using mappedBy and map this bidirectional so Contact need to have theses two columns one for client other for company.

Looking after [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table), the solution may be a little odd here. It's use a ManyToMany relationship unidirectional from Client and Company. And you don't need to have foreign keys in Client nor Company netheir in Contact. But will have to create a new table to intermediate this relationship.

The simple way to go is create a table for each relationship on table "Client_Contact" and other "Company_Contact" each on with to columns, one for client_id/company_id other for contact_id.col